# Difference between , and ;?

Tags: c++, c++11

**EDIT** Looks like I didn't explain myself in a good way. My question was not about the Rule of 3, or how to implement it in a good way. My question is why when using comma the destructors **are called after complete the sequence and not when the variables leave the scope**, I mean, the objets are only destroyed when all the functions between comma have finished, you can see it adding a cout to the destructors.

In this example,

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <cstring>    
using namespace std;    

class Libro {    
 char* titulo_; int paginas_;    
 public:    
 Libro() : titulo_(new char[1]), paginas_(0) {*titulo_= 0;}    
 Libro(const char* t, int p) : paginas_(p) {    
  titulo_ = new char[strlen(t) + 1];    
  strcpy(titulo_, t);    
}    
 ~Libro() { delete[] titulo_; }    
 void paginas(int p) { paginas_ = p; }    
 int paginas() const { return paginas_; }    
 char* titulo() const { return titulo_; }    
};    

void mostrar(Libro l) {    
cout << l.titulo() << " tiene " << l.paginas() << " paginas" << endl;    
}    

int main() {    
 Libro l1("Fundamentos de C++", 474), l2("Por Fin: C ISO", 224), l3;    
 l3 = l1;    
 mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3);  
}
```

Despite the copy constructor is not defined and the default copy constructor provide by the compiler is not valid in this case, the execution is correct and It shows the right information in the calls to *mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3);*.

However, if we use *mostrar(l1); mostrar(l2); mostrar(l3);* instead, we would have the expected error, the last call wouldn't show correctly the last call, because the copy haven't been done properly.
Do you know what is the diference between use , and ;? Why this code is working when you use ,?

Comment: this is definitely NOT c.

Comment: As the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Undefined behavior gives you undefined behavior.  You need to follow the rule of three

Comment: My question was why even the code is wrong the results using comma are always right. I know the code is wrong, the question is why the access to memory is right when using comma even when it supposed to be undefined, as happens using ;.

Comment: Undefined behavior includes "seems to work" as one possible outcome.

Comment: Sorry about all the downvotes. This is a tough crowd. Your question is a good one, you've unfortunately stumbled into a bug caused by 2 implicit behaviors. The rule of 3/5 is there to protect you from such, but obviously that hasn't been related to you. I've tried to clarify the issue in my answer. I'm also giving you a +1 to offset the ridiculous number of downvotes.

Comment: I have edited the question because I don't think I have explained well, the question is not about the code, is about why the compiler doesn't call destructors when the variables leave the scope when several functions are called in the same line with commas, instead, the destructors are called at the same time when the execution of the whole line is ended.

Comment: @jramirez Note that your edit to the question makes it an opinion based question in which we speculate about why the compiled program acts a certain way when it's behavior is undefined. You *cannot* expect a good answer here, what may be true for your compiler may be false for another version, even minor version of your compiler, and certainly could not be considered true for another environment. The point is that no one can give you anything more than an opinion about how undefined behavior will play out, *cause it's undefined.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not written a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator. [The Rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_Three) tells us that anytime a destructor has been written, the copy assignment operator and copy constructor should be as well. You haven't written either so let's look at what happens:

1. `l3 = l1` in this line the [implicitly defined copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) is called which will be defined like this:

```
Libro& Libro::operator=(const Libro& rhs) {
    this.tiulo_ = rhs.titulo_;
    this.paginas_ = rhs.paginas_;
}
```

2. `this.tiulo_ = rhs.titulo_` This means that both the `l1` and `l3` objects point to the "Fundamentos de C++" string that was dynamically allocated by `l1`'s constructor
3. `l3.~Libro()` is called implicitly as `l3` [leaves scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_programming)) which will call `delete [] titulo_` destroying the "Fundamentos de C++" dynamically allocated member of `l3` **which is also `l1`'s `titulo_` member**.
4. `l1.~Libro()` is called implicitly as well, which will call `delete [] titulo_` however this time that member was deleted by `l3` leaving scope, [for a deleted pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete):

> Passing it to a deallocation function (double-delete) is undefined behavior

So your issue is not the `,` versus the `;` but the double-delete that results from not following The Rule of 3.

---

If I may though, rather than suggesting you create a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, I'd suggest you do away with `Libro` and use [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) in a `pair your code would be as simple as this:

```
pair<string, int> l1 = make_pair("Fundamentos de C++"s, 474), l2 = make_pair("Por Fin: C ISO"s, 224), l3;
```

This will of course require you to explicitly output each member, for example:

```
cout << l1.first << " tiene " << l1.second << " paginas\n" << l2.first << " tiene " << l2.second << " paginas\n" << l3.first << " tiene " << l3.second << " paginas\n";
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/WqgyTh)

Comment: But even you don't respect the rule of three, the destructors are not called up to the " ; ", so when l3 has to access the data they are still there. While mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3) are executing, none destructor are called, they are all called when the execution arrive to the " ; ". My real question is why the compiler don't call the desctructors when the variables leaves the scope when you use commas. Thank you so much.

Comment: @jram I've left you a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612851/difference-between-and/45617306#comment78212973_45612851) about how an answer to this would be nothing more than an opinion. If you want my uneducated guess, it's that dev environment has unloaded it's debug checking at the end of main, before the destructors get called in the `,`-version. In the `;`-version it may be that the `Libro` objects destruction is optimized to happen after their last use... before the end of `main`. Please know that's just an opinion, and as such does not belong in a well formed answer.